# Video Editing in Iphone

Tags: iphone, video, editing, trim

In my application user should be able to select a video from video library and also should able to trim the video and play the video in a movie player. Can any one please help me???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the [AVFoundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html%23/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html). As you mentioned below, you want to use [the UIVideoEditorController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIVideoEditorController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Note that what you ask is only supported by the AVFoundation in iOS 4.0 and higher.

Comment: Also AVEditDemo from wwdc2010

Comment: Can I do it with UIImagePicker?

Comment: @Vineeth - No. UIImagePicker allows you to choose a photo from the photo library. Although, you may need something similar for part of your app.

Comment: What abt UIVideoEditorController? If yes How can edit using uivideoeditorcontroller?

Comment: @Vineeth - Yes, according to the documentation, you will need to use that class. Are you a registered (paid) developer? If yes, watch the mentioned WWDC video.

Comment: I have used UIVideoController Class to trim the video.in the delegate method - (void)videoEditorController:(UIVideoEditorController*)editor
     didSaveEditedVideoToPath:(NSString*)editedVideoPath; when i play the video at editedVideopath it plays the full video rather than the trimmed video. How can i get the path of the trimmed video?

Comment: @Vineeth - you probably need to save the trimmed video somewhere first.

Comment: I have saved it to photoalbum using  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum( editedVideoPath,
                                            self,
                                            @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                            NULL );.     
 Bur play the video at the videopath it plays the full video

Comment: Is there is any method to show photos in the photo library when we are selecting photos and videos in the video library when we are selecting the video using uiimage picker?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the sourceType of your UIImagePicker.

Comment: I was able to trim the video using uiimagepicker when the sourcetype is photolibrary. But when i use the camera source type i was able to edit the video but when i played that corresponding video it is not trimmed. why?

Answer (score 0):

Also check out this Apple's sample project. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVSimpleEditoriOS/Introduction/Intro.html
And for documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html#/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html